# Fixing a td's width

Tags: html, html-table, width

I've got a div in a td. The width of the content in the div is variable. When I click on the div, I change the div's position attribute from static to absolute. The td loses its width when I change the position attribute of the div within it.

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2A2rR/1/) for an illustration.

When the div changes from static to absolute positioning, I don't want the td to resize. How?

Comment: I don't see the td width collapsing in jsfiddle

Comment: @alquatoun Click it and you should

Comment: ahh, weird. doesn't do it in Chrome. collapses in FF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The td is resizing because the div, which is creating the width of the td, is taking out of the natural document flow. The td considers itself as having no relation to the div at this point.

You'll need to set the width of the td in accordance with the width of the div if you want it to retain that size.

**UPDATE**

Here's one way you can quite quickly acheive what you're after: http://jsfiddle.net/2A2rR/3/
(it's not perfect but you get the general idea)

Comment: Yeah I figured. Just checking to see if there was some CSS only way of doing this.

Comment: I dont think there is (that I know of). What I'd probably do is grab the content of the div, put it in an absolutely positioned div, and set the current div to be invisible. That'll keep your size and acheive the affect you're after.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('#widthKeeper').click(function() {
           var divWidth = $("table tr td:firstchild").css(width);
           jQuery(this).css('position', 'absolute');
           jQuery("table tr td:firstchild").css('width',divWidth);
    });
});
```